# csv modify file

Tags: c#, csv

I am a bit in a pickle regarding a consolidation application we are using in our company. We create a csv file from an progress database this csv file has 14 columns and NO header.

The CSV file contains payments (around 173 thousand rows). Most of these rows are the same except for the column amount (last column)

Example:

```
2014;MONTH;;SC;10110;;;;;;;;EUR;-6500000
2014;01;;SC;10110;;;;;;;;EUR;-1010665
2014;01;;LLC;11110;;;;;;;;EUR;-6567000
2014;01;;SC;10110;;;;;;;;EUR;-1110665
2014;01;;LLC;11110;;;;;;;;EUR;65670.00
2014;01;;SC;10110;;;;;;;;EUR;-11146.65
```

(around 174000 rows)

As you can see some of these lines are the same except for the amount column. What i need is to sort all rows, add up the amount and save one unique row instead of 1100 rows with different amounts.

My coding skills are failing me to get the job done within a certain timeframe, maybe one of you can push me in the right direction solving this problem.

Example code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\test.txt");
            string inputLine = "";
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(input);
            List<List<string>> data = new List<List<string>>();
            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (inputLine.Trim().Length > 0)
                {
                    string[] inputArray = inputLine.Split(new char[] { ';' });
                    data.Add(inputArray.ToList());
                }
            }
            //sort data by every column
            for (int sortCol = data[0].Count() - 1; sortCol >= 0; sortCol--)
            {
                data.OrderBy(x => x[sortCol]); 
            }
            //delete duplicate rows
            for (int rowCount = data.Count - 1; rowCount >= 1; rowCount--)
            {
                Boolean match = true;
                for (int colCount = 0; colCount < data[rowCount].Count - 2; colCount++)
                {
                    if(data[rowCount][colCount] != data[rowCount - 1][colCount])
                    {
                        match = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (match == true)
                {
                    decimal previousValue = decimal.Parse(data[rowCount - 1][data[rowCount].Count - 1]);
                    decimal currentValue = decimal.Parse(data[rowCount][data[rowCount].Count - 1]);
                    string newStrValue = (previousValue + currentValue).ToString();
                    data[rowCount - 1][data[rowCount].Count - 1] = newStrValue;
                    data.RemoveAt(rowCount);
                }
            }

            string output = string.Join("\r\n",data.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(x => string.Join(";",x.Select(y => y).ToArray())).ToArray());
            File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\test1.txt",output);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what you  have tried so  far

Comment: Is the input file reasonably small such that it can be completely read into memory?

Comment: If you create the CSV file from a database, it implies you can work directly with the database?  This would be a lot easier to do at the database level.

Comment: Why not just open it in Excel?

Comment: Why should my users do it in excel instead of just do it automaticly for them.

Comment: @cel0x It wasn't clear that this was more than a one-time deal. If this .csv file is created on a regular basis, I would suggest modifying the application that creates the csv file to create the file your users want instead.

Comment: @EricFinn it is not possible to do this at the source.

Answer (score 2):

Read the CSV file line by line, and build an in-memory dictionary in which you keep the totals (and other information you require). As most of the lines belong to the same key, it will probably not cause out of memory issues. Afterwards, generate a new CSV based on the information in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

As I interpret your question, your problem and the solution you are asking for are how to take your input that are in the form of

```
@"2014;MONTH;;SC;10110;;;;;;;;EUR;-6500000
2014;01;;SC;10110;;;;;;;;EUR;-1010665
2014;01;;LLC;11110;;;;;;;;EUR;-6567000
2014;01;;SC;10110;;;;;;;;EUR;-1110665
2014;01;;LLC;11110;;;;;;;;EUR;65670.00
2014;01;;SC;10110;;;;;;;;EUR;-11146.65"
```

Get the last column and then sum it up? If so this is actually very easy to do with something like this

```
public static void Main()
    {
        string input = @"2014;MONTH;;SC;10110;;;;;;;;EUR;-6500000
2014;01;;SC;10110;;;;;;;;EUR;-1010665
2014;01;;LLC;11110;;;;;;;;EUR;-6567000
2014;01;;SC;10110;;;;;;;;EUR;-1110665
2014;01;;LLC;11110;;;;;;;;EUR;65670.00
2014;01;;SC;10110;;;;;;;;EUR;-11146.65";

        var rows = input.Split('\n');

        decimal totalValue = 0m;

        foreach(var row in rows)
        {           
            var transaction = row.Substring(row.LastIndexOf(';') +1);

            decimal val = 0m;

            if(decimal.TryParse(transaction, out val))
                totalValue += val;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(totalValue);
    }
```

But maybe I have misunderstood what you were asking for?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry answering my post so late but this is my final solution

Replacing all " characters and write the output to the stream writer. (going from 25mb to a 15mb file.). Than copy my CSV file to the SQL server so i can bulk insert. After my insert i just query the table and read / write the result set to a new file. My new file is only +/-700KB!

The Filldata() method is filling a datagridview in my application so you can review the result instead of opening the file in excel.

I am new with C#, i am currently writing a new solution to query the csv file directly or in memory and write it back to a new file.

Method1:

```
                string line;

                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(insertFile);

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sourcePath))
                {
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(line.Replace("\"", ""));
                    }

                    sr.Close();
                    sw.Close();
                    sr.Dispose();
                    sw.Dispose();

                    File.Copy(insertFile, @"\\SQLSERVER\C$\insert.csv");

                }
```

Method2:

```
var destinationFile = @"c:\insert.csv";

                var querieImportCSV = "BULK INSERT dbo.TABLE FROM '" + destinationFile + "' WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = ';', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', FIRSTROW = 1)";
                var truncate = @"TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.TABLE";

              string queryResult =
      @"SELECT [Year]
              ,[Month]
              ,[Week]
              ,[Entity]
              ,[Account]
              ,[C11]
              ,[C12]
              ,[C21]
              ,[C22]
              ,[C3]
              ,[C4]
              ,[CTP]
              ,[VALUTA]
              ,SUM(AMOUNT) as AMOUNT
              ,[CURRENCY_ORIG]
              ,[AMOUNTEXCH]
              ,[AGENTCODE]
            FROM dbo.TABLE
            GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH, WEEK, Entity, Account, C11, C12, C21, C22, C3, C4, CTP, VALUTA, CURRENCY_ORIG, AMOUNTEXCH, AGENTCODE
            ORDER BY Account";

                var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand commandTruncate = new SqlCommand(truncate, conn);
                commandTruncate.ExecuteNonQuery();

                SqlCommand commandInsert = new SqlCommand(querieImportCSV, conn);
                SqlDataReader readerInsert = commandInsert.ExecuteReader();
                readerInsert.Close();

                FillData();

                SqlCommand commandResult = new SqlCommand(queryResult, conn);
                SqlDataReader readerResult = commandResult.ExecuteReader();

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 

                while (readerResult.Read())
                {
                        sb.Append(readerResult["Year"] + ";" + readerResult["Month"] + ";" + readerResult["Week"] + ";" + readerResult["Entity"] + ";" + readerResult["Account"] + ";" +
                        readerResult["C11"] + ";" + readerResult["C12"] + ";" + readerResult["C21"] + ";" + readerResult["C22"] + ";" + readerResult["C3"] + ";" + readerResult["C4"] + ";" +
                        readerResult["CTP"] + ";" + readerResult["Valuta"] + ";" + readerResult["Amount"] + ";" + readerResult["CURRENCY_ORIG"] + ";" + readerResult["AMOUNTEXCH"] + ";" + readerResult["AGENTCODE"]);
                }
                sb.Replace("\"","");

                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(homedrive);
                sw.WriteLine(sb);

                readerResult.Close();
                conn.Close();
                sw.Close();
                sw.Dispose();
```